# How to Run Pytorch Bert with AMD

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, amd-gpu

github code: https://github.com/bellowman/Deep-Learning-Practice/blob/main/BioBert%20for%20Multi%20Label%20AMD.ipynb

Hello everyone,

I am a beginner with pytorch, tensorflow, and BERT. I have a machine at home with an AMD Ryzen 7 1800x and a Radeon RX 6600 video card.

I am trying to run a bioBERT model at home. I have trouble leveraging my model to use my AMD card. I posted my github notebook. I have troubles in cell 3 and 9.

1. First Question: In cell 3,I am trying to convert the bioBERT weight to PyTorch with transformmer-cli. I get the warning of "Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'". Does this affect performance later?
2. Second Question: In cell 9, My model load is really slow because it is using just the CPU. How can I get the model to run on my AMD GPU

Comment: Well you can't load the cudart dll because you don't have the right graphics card for that. To use PyTorch with AMD you need to follow [this](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-for-amd-rocm-platform-now-available-as-python-package/). Another option is just using google colab and loading that ipynb and then you won't have those issues.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with Google Colab, but I do want to make this work with AMD.

Was wondering if anyone knows the exact code change or steps to make it work with AMD

Comment: Did you install PyTorch with the ROC-m package? The code in the cell might not be the problem, it is most likely that you have the wrong PyTorch installed.

Comment: Ahh, it seems like I have to do this on linux to make this work. Thank you for the advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [chrispresso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2599709/chrispresso)

AMD ROCm seems to be the way to go, but it requires one to run under linux